# Area of portion of circle inside a square.

Tags: geometry, puzzle, area

Consider a square grazing field with each side of length 8 metres. There is a pillar at the
centre of the field (i.e. at the intersection of the two diagonals). A cow is tied to the pillar
using a rope of length $8\over\sqrt3$ meters. Find the area of the part of the field that the cow is allowed
to graze.

[image: Find area of shaded region (measurements given are approximate values only)]

Comment: What have you tried? How about dissecting the area into pieces you can find the area of and adding the areas uo?

Comment: @Conrad Turner I thought about doing that, but I couldn't come up with a way to deal with the corners.

Comment: Join the centre to the points where the circle and square cut one another. Then you have four triangles that you can find the area of, and four sectors of the circle which when you have found their central angle you can find the areas of.

Comment: See also: [Overlapping area between a circle and a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1450961).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's calculate the central angle of each segment in the circle which is cut off by the square.

[image]

Let $\angle BAC=\theta$. It is given that $AC=4$, and $AB={8 \over \sqrt3}$.

From the figure it is easy to deduce that in $\Delta ABC$, $\cos\theta={\sqrt3 \over 2}$,
which means that $\theta=30^\circ$ and hence the central angle $\angle BAG$ is equal to $60^\circ$.

The area of a segment in a circle of radius $R$, of central angle $\alpha$ is $$area={R^2 \over 2}{\left( {\pi\alpha \over 180^\circ}-\sin\alpha \right)}$$

So now all you have to do is calculate the area cut off by the four segments together, and then subtract it from the total area of the circle.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know that we actually had a formula to calculate the area of a "segment" of a circle ! very elagant.

Comment: @G-man No, $\theta$ was the half of the central angle, not the whole central angle, so the central angle is $2\theta$. The triangle $\triangle ABG$ is equilateral so that the area of it is equal to $R^2\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}=\frac{1}{2}R^2\cdot \sin{2\theta}=\frac{1}{2}R^2\cdot \sin{60^{\circ}}$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$|OA|=\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}\\
|OC|=4\\
|AC|=\frac{16}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\cos \angle AOC = |OC|/|OA| = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \cos 30° ⇒ \angle AOC = 30°$$

So, we arrive at the angle subtended by sector is also 30 degrees (there is another triangle like AOC (not shown in figure) with apex angle 30 degrees ⇒ angle subtended by sector $= 90° - (30°+30°) = 30°$)

$$\text{Area} = 2*\text{area of triangle $OAC$} + \text{Area of sector $OAB$}\\
\text{Area of sector $OAB$} = 30°/360° (π⋅\frac{64}{3}) = π⋅\frac{16}{9}\\
\text{Area of triangle $OAC$} = |AC|⋅|OC|/2 = \frac{32}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Final answer: $\frac{64}{\sqrt{3}} + π⋅\frac{16}{9}$

Comment: I think it should be $|AC| = \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$ and in the end you forgot to multiply everything by the factor $4$ of sectors.