# Overlapping area between a circle and a square

Tags: geometry, circles, area, polygons

I have a circle and a square. They are aligned to their center. The radius of the given circle is less then half the value of diameter of the square.

How to find the overlapped area?

Comment: You haven't supplied enough information for the problem. The size of the objects isn't the only consideration -- their relative positions must also be known. For example, are they centered at the same point? Is the circle centered at a corner of the square? Etc.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. The circle and the square are aligned to their center.

Comment: If they have the same center then they always overlap, whether the radius of the circle is less than half the diameter of the square or not.

Comment: That was a question asked to verify the overlapping. ANd the rhetoric nature confused some people. I modifed the question now.

Comment: Assume the circle has unit radius, and the sides of square has length $2u$. The area is trivial for $u \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $u \ge 1$. For $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \le u \le 1$. You first compute the area of what's remain in the circle if you remove the square from it and then subtract this number from $\pi$. You can compute this by calculus or by treating each the 4 remaining piece as a difference of a circular sector and a triangle.

Answer (score 3):

Let $r$ be the radius of the circle and $a$ be *half* the length of a side of the square.

If $r \leq a$ then the overlapping area is the area of the whole circle $\pi r^2$.

If $r \geq a \sqrt{2}$ then the overlapping area is the area of the whole square $a^2$.

Now to the more interesting case where $a < r < a\sqrt{2}$.
[image]

Exploiting the symmetry of the problem we divide the plane to 8 parts as shown in the picture, so that the overlapping area is 8 times the colored area.

Let $\theta = \arccos(a/r)$ the angle shown in the picture.
The blue area is a circular sector of angle $\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta$ so its area equals $(\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta)\frac{r^2}{2}$.
The red triangle has area $\frac{1}{2}ar\sin\theta$.

Putting all these together, the total overlapping area is
$(\pi-4\theta)r^2+4ar\sin\theta$.